# Reading data from this text file into datetime objects in Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Anyone please help me in changing time format in python.

file has format:

```
yyyy    ddd    hh:mm:ss    hh:mm:ss   
2015     1      00:00:00    17:56:21      
2015     1      00:01:00    17:56:35      
2015     1      00:02:00    17:56:49      
2015     1      00:03:00    17:57:03      
2015     1      00:04:00    17:57:17     
2015     1      00:05:00    17:57:30      
2015     1      00:06:00    17:57:44      
2015     1      00:07:00    17:57:58      
2015     1      00:08:00    17:58:11    
.
.
.
few hundred thousand records.
```

What I did here:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Themis.txt', delimiter="    ", skiprows=33)
df.head()

yyyy ddd hh mm ss hh mm ss  X   Y   Z
0   2015 1 00:00:00 17:56:21    -1.07   9.27    2.58
1   2015 1 00:01:00 17:56:35    -1.08   9.28    2.58
2   2015 1 00:02:00 17:56:49    -1.09   9.29    2.58
3   2015 1 00:03:00 17:57:03    -1.10   9.30    2.58
4   2015 1 00:04:00 17:57:17    -1.12   9.32    2.58

df.columns

Index(['yyyy    ddd    hh mm ss    hh mm ss', 'X', '    Y', '    Z'], dtype='object')
```

First column contains all date n time and no month, this column is the main problem. I want a column in the form: 2015-1-1 00:03:00 (only first hh:mm:ss).

```
df.values

       ['2015   1 03:01:00 18:37:21', -3.12, 10.9, 1.67],
       ['2015   1 03:02:00 18:37:35', -3.13, 10.9, 1.66],
       ['2015   1 03:03:00 18:37:50', -3.14, 10.91, 1.65],
       ['2015   1 03:04:00 18:38:04', -3.16, 10.91, 1.64],
       ['2015   1 03:05:00 18:38:19', -3.17, 10.92, 1.63],
       ['2015   1 03:06:00 18:38:33', -3.18, 10.92, 1.62],
       ['2015   1 03:07:00 18:38:48', -3.19, 10.93, 1.62]], dtype=object)
```

Anyone please help me to get required time format.

Thanking you

Comment: it seems as though your file may be fixed-width format? if so, [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) is more appropriate. In any case, it does not appear that you're actually splitting the whitespace - it seems your delimiter is too many spaces. You could try `delimiter="\s+"` to use one (or more) space characters as the delimiter.

Comment: Also, what is 'ddd'? Day of the year?

Comment: @ Michael Delgado, Thank you, let me try as you suggested.

Comment: @ FObersteiner, Yes. yyyy= year, ddd= day